# How to count each DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to count how many of each hit I get from distinct.
So the beginning:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM dbtable
```

That gives me 6 different categories, fine.
Now I want to count each row so the result looks like this:

```
category, 4
category, 8
category, 12
category, 72
category, 5
category, 65
```

Ive tried:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT category) FROM dbtable
```

That gives my the first categorys amount...

Here I am stuck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM dbtable
GROUP BY category;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM dbtable GROUP BY category
```

**Please notice that:**

- You need GROUP BY to gather data so DB server can count each rows and filter it by your categories, without it server don't know which rows to count;
- You must remember that Group By clause will always come at the end of
  the SQL query, just like the Order by clause.
- You **dont need DISTINCT** because GROUP BY make this job. (Thanks jarlh)

You can find more explanation with fiddles here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: That DISTINCT makes no difference, the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use group by and count like:

```
SELECT category,count(category) FROM dbtable GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
  SELECT category, COUNT(1) FROM dbtable GROUP BY category
```

And If u want specific count Record then try this

```
   SELECT category, COUNT(1) FROM dbtable GROUP BY category having count(1)>10
```